# Java: Telling JVM to treat all fields/methods as public

Tags: java, testing, jvm, public

I'm going through a java codebase and think that it would be much easier to see how the software works if I could temporarily make all fields and methods public.

The access specifiers are basically guidelines to be followed by the programmer `while he is coding`(ex. use setter instead of direct assignment to allow the setter to perform some other work associated with the field).
Is it possible to tell jvm to ignore the access limiters when running a java program?

Another possibility might be to use some IDE plugin which manually changes the visibility of everything to `public`.

Comment: **No**. And that is a terrible idea.

Comment: Why do this in the JVM?  It mostly only makes a difference at compile time.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is  your IDE's debugger.  It lets you step through your code and see the values of all variables whenever you like, regardless of whether they're public, protected or private.

Comment: Part of the point of restricting visibility in the first place is that it allows you to reason about the parts of code that need to care about the access-restricted elements. If something is private, you know that you only need to care about the compilation unit it is in. Making things public basically means you have to care about how all code interacts with it. In short: you'd be making your job far, far harder.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for won't work on a number of levels.

1. You can't do this at the source code / compilation level.  It alters the Java language.   And it wouldn't achieve anything either.
2. You can't do this in any useful fashion at runtime.  You could use reflection to make the fields accessible.  However, it is impractical because:

   - This must be done one `Field` at a time, or one `Class` at a time; e.g.

     ```
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true);
     ```
   - You would need to retain all of the `Field` objects so "treated", because setting a `Field` object to be accessible doesn't affect other `Field` objects for the same field.
   - You could only make use of this if you modified your source code to use reflection and the above `Field` objects to access the field values.
3. If you are trying to understand how your code works, there are other better ways to do it.

   - Read and analyze the source code.  Use an IDE to help you with this.
   - Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to see the state of a variable *irrespective of the variable's access*.  And it works for parameters and local variables as well as fields.
   - Add some debug logging or trace prints to your code.  (And remove the changes when you are finished your investigation.  Use version control to help you back out the changes.)

---

> @ElliottFrisch Why is it a bad idea?

Basically, because it won't help you.

Comment: Access override doesn’t need to “be done one field at a time”. You can pass an array of `Field` instances to [`AccessibleObject.setAccessible(theArray, true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,boolean)). But it must be emphasized that this doesn’t change the access level of the fields, but only the particular `Field` instances. So the access must happen precisely through these `Field` instances, not other `Field` instances representing the same fields…

Comment: Didn't know that.   Fixed.

Comment: When you do `AccessibleObject.setAccessible(clazz.getDeclaredFields(), true)`, you gain nothing. As said, you must use the very `Field` instances whose accessible state you changed, hence, `Field[] theFieldInstancesToUse = clazz.getDeclaredFields();  AccessibleObject.setAccessible(theFieldInstancesToUse, true); /* use the elements of theFieldInstancesToUse */`. The next call to `clazz.getDeclaredFields()` will return different instances. In principle, you can build and pass arbitrary `Field[]` arrays to that method, however, I suppose we agree that it still is complicated…

Comment: The point is that it is way too complicated to do it for every field of every class (as the OP is asking), and it doesn't help him do what he is really trying to do anyway.

Comment: Full agreement here. It’s complicated and not even helping. And it will stop working in future versions, as since Java 9, it’s supposed to be restricted to modules opened to the caller. There’s just a grace period to allow adapting existing software.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is definitely achievable but raises some questions as to why you might want or need to do it. There is almost always a reason behind setting access modifiers. In fact it may help you to understand the software more if you have a think about why certain fields and methods are made public etc.

I recently started a new job where I had to go through a large codebase and try to understand what everything does. I found that using a *Debugger* was the best way to *step* through the code and have a look at the value of each field, variable etc at each point in the program. All good Java IDES have debuggers. I use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which has a very useful debugger that even allows you to run custom evaluation statements at different points in the running of a program.

Comment: `why you might want or need to do it` I'm looking at the implementation of a data structure and think it would be helpful if I could look at the various fields and query it's properties.

Comment: In that case a debugger will do exactly what you need! [This page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html) will be helpful in learning how to use the IntelliJ IDEA debugging tool.

Comment: @saga you can access all fields using reflection if you really need to.  This way you can access them regardless of their access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally considered **High Treason** by the Style Guide.

Options:

- You can still use java reflection to set fields (private, final, or otherwise), but the downside is that you can't code as if it is public, you still have to call some method to set a field to bla.
- Use JNI which to link C code to java, and C really doesn't really care about Java's field visibility.

A compiler plugin would probably work, but by the time most programmers get to the point of knowing how, they also know what a bad idea it was. Granted, I am tempted to try now.

Note:
I am reasonably sure java's `SecurityManager` would take issue with you trying to make it's data public.